# Convert curl to jquery post with json payload

Tags: jquery, json, post, curl

I'm trying to "convert" the following working curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d
    "{"""username""":"""myuser""", """password""":"""nastypassword"""}"
    http://website.com/api/v1.0/login
```

to a jquery call.

The most important thing is that on the server-side I need to get the **json** data because I'm using flask and the `request.json` to get the data.

I have tried the following in many variations:

```
$.ajax('http://website.com/api/v1.0/login', {
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json', // I don't think this needs to be here because of dataType
    data: {
        username: 'myuser',
        password: 'nastypassword'
    }
})
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + ' - ' + error);
    });
```

How do I get jquery to send the json?

I should probably add that I'm creating a cordova application. and `access origin` is set to `*`. `GET` works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want

```
$.ajax('http://website.com/api/v1.0/login', {
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json', // I don't think this needs to be here because of dataType
  data: {
    username: 'myuser',
    password: 'nastypassword'
  },
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error){
    alert(status + ' - ' + error);
  }
});
```